# How to replace string character pattern using python in csv file

Tags: python

I am new to python. How to replace string character `,"` to `,{` and `",` to `},` which contains multilines in .csv file?

Here is my content of .csv file

```
Name, Degree,Some, Occupation, Object
Mr. A,"B.A, M.A",123,"ags,gshs",ass
Mr. ABC,"B.A, M.A",231,"ags,gshs",asas
Mr. D,"BB.A, M.A",44,"ags,gshs",asas
Mr. G,"BBBB.A, M.A",12,"ags,gshs",asasasa
Mr. S,"B.A, MMM.A",10,"ags,gshs",asasas
Mr. R,"B.A, M.A",11,"ags,gshs",asasas
Mr. T,"B.A, M.A",12,"ags,gshs",asasa
Mr. DD,"B.A, M.A",13,"ags,gshs",asasas
```

So my output will be something like this

```
 Name, Degree,Some, Occupation, Obejct
 Mr. A,{B.A, M.A},123,{ags,gshs},ass
 Mr. ABC,{B.A, M.A},231,{ags,gshs},asas
 Mr. D,{BB.A, M.A},44,{ags,gshs},asas
 Mr. G,{BBBB.A, M.A},12,{ags,gshs},asasasa
 Mr. S,{B.A, MMM.A},10,{ags,gshs},asasas
 Mr. R,{B.A, M.A},11,{ags,gshs},asasas
 Mr. T,{B.A, M.A},12,{ags,gshs},asasa
 Mr. DD,{B.A, M.A},13,{ags,gshs},asasas
```

Comment: If python is not a requirement, you could also use tools like `sed` or `awk` to modify the CSV file in place.

Answer (score 3):

After opening the file with `file.read()`, you can use `replace(old, new)`  to replace the string characters you desire. Keep in mind, since the strings `,"` and `",` contain quotes, you must put a `\` before the quotes to show they part of the string.

EDIT: A comment mentioned you could enclose the string in `' '`. If you do this, putting `\` before the quotes is not required. For example, both `",\""` and `',"'` are valid strings.

```
data = ""

with open("/path/to/file.csv") as file:
     data = file.read().replace(",\"", ",{").replace("\",", "},")

with open("/path/to/new_file.csv") as file:
     file.write(data)
```

Comment: Or use single-quotes for values containing double-quotes: `',"'`

Answer (score 0):

If you only need it once you could use pandas like this:

```
import pandas as pd

data1 = '''\
Name,Degree,Some,Occupation,Object
Mr. A,"B.A, M.A",123,"ags,gshs",ass
Mr. ABC,"B.A, M.A",231,"ags,gshs",asas
Mr. D,"BB.A, M.A",44,"ags,gshs",asas
Mr. G,"BBBB.A, M.A",12,"ags,gshs",asasasa
Mr. S,"B.A, MMM.A",10,"ags,gshs",asasas
Mr. R,"B.A, M.A",11,"ags,gshs",asasas
Mr. T,"B.A, M.A",12,"ags,gshs",asasa
Mr. DD,"B.A, M.A",13,"ags,gshs",asasas'''

df = pd.read_csv(pd.compat.StringIO(data1), sep=',', dtype=object)
#df = pd.read_csv('input.csv', sep=',', dtype=object)  # Use this row for real application

df['Degree'] = '{'+df['Degree']+'}'
df['Occupation'] = '{'+df['Occupation']+'}'

# Create custom output
out = '\n'.join([','.join(df.columns), '\n'.join(','.join(i) for i in df.values)])

with open('output.csv') as f:
    f.write(out)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use unpacking:

```
import csv
with open('filename.csv') as f:
  data = filter(None, list(csv.reader(f)))
  with open('filename.csv', 'w') as f1:
    write = csv.writer(f1)
    write.writerows([data[0]]+[[a, '{'+b+'}', c, '{'+d+'}', e] for a, b, c, d, e in data[1:]])
```

Output:

```
Name, Degree,Some, Occupation, Object
Mr. A,{B.A, M.A},123,{ags,gshs},ass
Mr. ABC,{B.A, M.A},231,{ags,gshs},asas
Mr. D,{BB.A, M.A},44,{ags,gshs},asas
Mr. G,{BBBB.A, M.A},12,{ags,gshs},asasasa
Mr. S,{B.A, MMM.A},10,{ags,gshs},asasas
Mr. R,{B.A, M.A},11,{ags,gshs},asasas
Mr. T,{B.A, M.A},12,{ags,gshs},asasa
Mr. DD,{B.A, M.A},13,{ags,gshs},asasas
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
def find_replace(csv_path, search_characters, replace_with):
    text = open(csv_path, "r")
    text = ''.join([i for i in text]).replace(
        search_characters, replace_with)
    x = open(csv_path, "w")
    x.writelines(text)
    x.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    csv_path = "path/to/csv/file.csv"
    search_characters = ',"'
    replace_with = ',{'

    find_replace(csv_path, search_characters, replace_with)

    search_characters = '",'
    replace_with = '},'

    find_replace(csv_path, search_characters, replace_with)
```

The above code opens the file, writes some data to it and then closes it.

Or, if you prefer `list`s as well the `with` statement which will take care to call `__exit__` function of the given object even if something bad happened in code.

```py
def find_replace(csv_path, search_characters, replace_with):
    s_one, s_two = search_characters
    r_one, r_two = replace_with
    with open(csv_path) as file:
        data = file.read().replace(s_one, r_one).replace(s_two, r_two)
    with open(csv_path, 'w') as file:
        file.write(data)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    csv_path = "path/to/csv/file.csv"
    
    search_characters = [',"', '",']
    replace_with = [',{', '},']

    find_replace(csv_path, search_characters, replace_with)
```

The main advantage of using a `with` statement is that it makes sure our file is closed without paying attention to how the nested block exits.

Tested and works nicely on your example.

Answer (score 0):

## Replacing string character pattern using python in csv file

```
text = open("input.csv", "r")
#text = ''.join([i for i in text]).replace("character to be replaced", "character to be replaced with")
text = ''.join([i for i in text]).replace(",\"", ",{")
#Replacing character from replaced text
text1 = ''.join([i for i in text]).replace("\",", "},")
x = open("output.csv","w")
x.writelines(text1)
x.close()
```