# Python replace txt data with csv data

Tags: python, string, csv, replace, txt

I have two files, one is text file and the other is a csv file.
The text file has a string format like this

```
To:      {email}
From:    noreply@deals.com
Subject: Deals!

Hi {first_name},
```

I want to replace `email` and `first_name` with some data I have in the csv file.

I write this code, but I couldn't replace the values

```
import csv
with open ("emails.csv","r")as csvfile:
    rows = csv.reader(csvfile)

    with open ("email_template.txt","r", encoding="utf8") as efile:
        my_string = efile.read()
        my_string =''.join(i for i in my_string).replace("email","555")
        print(my_string)
        for row in rows:
            print (row[0]+ " " +str(row[2]))
```

Comment: Hi and welcome! Why not using some punctuation marks?

Comment: it's first time for me to use this website, I don't know how to use it actually, I need help for solving my code

Comment: You need to share some demo data for the CSV as the answer depends on it

Comment: Where did the **"555"** come from?

Comment: Try looking at [How to replace string character pattern using Python in csv file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49633711/16653700).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the following approach:

```py
import csv

with open('email_template.txt') as f_template:
    template = f_template.read()
    
with open('emails.csv') as f_emails:
    csv_emails = csv.DictReader(f_emails)
    
    for row in csv_emails:
        output = template.replace('{email}', row['email']).replace('{first_name}', row['first_name'])
        print(output)
```

1. First read the whole template into a `template` string.
2. Use a Python `DictReader()` to read the CSV a line at a time into a `row` dictionary.
3. Take the template and replace your two fields with text from the row.
4. Print the output.

So if your `emails.csv` file was as follows:

```
first_name,last_name,email
Fred,Flintstone,ff@bedrock.com
Wilma,Flintstone,wf@bedrock.com
```

You would get the following output:

```
To:      ff@bedrock.com
From:    noreply@deals.com
Subject: Deals!

Hi Fred,

To:      wf@bedrock.com
From:    noreply@deals.com
Subject: Deals!

Hi Wilma,
```